# How, and why, did Ancient Chinese hold banners displaying the type of work a person was undertaking?

Tags: ancient-china

1. Please show pictures of these banners? I am curious how they look.
2. What "type of work" and "work" would these banners display?
3. Why would the Chinese hold up "a  banner displaying the type of work a person was undertaking" with a hand? This procedure feels inefficient and grueling!
4. Wouldn't the Chinese's hand ache and twinge from lifting up a banner for a long time?  Instead of heaving a banner with your bare hand, why not erect and hang it up somewhere, like a tree?  Why not improvisate a flag or banner pole?

Christopher Seely and Kenneth G. Henshall, *The Complete Guide to Japanese Kanji*, page 622. [OBI = Oracle Bone Inscriptions (Late Shang Dynasty)](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/71563/how-and-why-did-the-chinese-hold-banners-displaying-the-type-of-work-a-person?noredirect=1#comment232753_71563) dates to [1766 - 1122 BCE](https://www.worldhistory.org/image/16125/chinese-dynasties-visual-timeline/).

> [image]

Comment: OBI = Oracle Bone Inscriptions (Late Shang Dynasty). I imagine sometjing like a British police officer holding up their warrant card.

Comment: Is this a history question?

Comment: Welcome to our forum. I hope you find the help you are looking for. That being said, I believe you will get much better help in the [Japanese Language Stack Exchange](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/). So, I suggest you copy this question, then close it, then paste it over there. I will vote to close this in a few days if it receives no help. Again, though, I suspect you will get much better and more prompt help over on the Japanese Stack.

Comment: Please provide a little more context. For example, when? Is this 1930s?

Comment: Actually not kooky at all to have your job written somewhere close to where you work. E.g. if you are s receptionist you will probably work near a sign that reads "reception desk". Though I imagine if you got a guy with a banner standing next to you it is more about representation than about information.

Comment: FWIW Modern Chinese seem to imagine something similar to the red banner next to yellow bear in [this caricature](https://www.reddit.com/r/MapPorn/comments/12hbwku/the_situation_in_the_far_east/), though in this case the content of the banner is more similar to a name rather than a title or a job description.

Comment: @kimchilover Yes.

Comment: @JimmyG. Thanks. I am asking about history here, not language though. Please don't close this.

Comment: @LarsBosteen Seeley wrote "OBI and bronze stages". Thanks [Spencer](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/71563/how-and-why-did-the-chinese-hold-banners-displaying-the-type-of-work-a-person?noredirect=1#comment232753_71563) for defining it! Therefore before 3rd century BC.

Comment: @user1176240 I am not sure I understand what you are asking, then. Can you clarify. Is the question "Why did people display their professions?" As in, was there some law or something mandating it? Is that the question?

Comment: I did read that in (at least some) cities in medieval Europe, guilds would be the basis for organizing many aspects of a city: militia companies, religious ceremonies... In that aspect it would not be that different [citation needed].

Comment: @JimmyG. As I read it, OP has a text saying a certain kanji character is a stylised representation of a hand holding a sign showing the holder's profession. They're assuming that this must mean that people used to actually do that, and they want to know where/why that was.

Comment: As @TobyY says, the character shows a hand holding a banner indicating trade or profession. It doesn't mean the Chinese people personally held banners, but they would of course have needed to display some sign outside their premises indicating what line of business they were in. Otherwise how could they attract customers?

Comment: @JimmyG. ""Why did people display their professions?" Yes, I want to know this too. But I am puzzled by the harrowing manner in which the Chinese did this. Please see my edits.

Comment: @TobyY.  Your comment appears correct.

Comment: Much as I hate to state the obvious, the fact that *artwork* includes a banner indicating what work a person does doesn't mean they actually did it. Realism in arts is relatively recent, and lots of paintings depict people doing symbolic things that they wouldn't have actually done in real life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re. points 1 and 2: These characters appeared about 3000 years ago, and there are few primary sources from that time. So it is hard to tell how exactly such banners would have looked or what would have been depicted or written on them.

Re. points 3 and 4: yes, this would be hard and not really productive, but that might be part of the point? That you can have a servant who holds a banner with a job description like "Important boss who will make the peasants work"? There are actual (though much more recent) [depictions](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ch%27iu_Ying_001.jpg) of people doing similar kind of work, i.e. holding stuff up for people far above them in social hierarchy. Therefore, someone holding a banner for an official does not sound implausible at all.

Another great source of depictions with people holding *things* to make their bosses look more prestigious are the Ming and Qing era versions of the ["Along the river during the Qingming festival" paintings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Along_the_River_During_the_Qingming_Festival). In the Song era version it is not so apparent for some reason. However, keep in mind that these are only 300 to 500 years old. In European terms that would be like using paintings from 17th century Greece to illustrate points about the Mycaenean civilation. But I think they can be used to prove a general point: If you are high enough in the hierarchy, you can have people doing stuff that serves no real purpose except representation.

From [one of the Ming era versions](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Qingming_in_Brief.jpg): [image: Official at the entrance of his house]

From [one of the Qing era versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Along_the_River_During_the_Qingming_Festival_(Qing_Court_Version).jpg):
[image: Official travelling]

One particularly striking example is from the same Ming dynasty version as above, but (I am guessing) seems to involve foreigners rather than an official:
[image: Group on horseback with camels]

---

That said, [Chinese internet sources](https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E5%90%8F/10913826) usually give a **different explanation** for that character: that it depicts a hand holding a hunting net (for hunting birds maybe?), and that the character originally meant "to hunt". According to these sources, the meaning of "to administer" only came later.

Chinese characters acquiring a new and unrelated meaning is actually not that rare. One well-known example is 象, which originally means elephant, but because being pronounced exactly as 像 has taken a lot of that other character's meaning (i.e. "shape" or "to resemble").

Comment: This is all the way back in the Shang dynasty or earlier, hence the reference to Oracle Bone Inscriptions.

Comment: @Spencer fair enough. I have changed my answer a bit.

Comment: It's even common today. In Holland we have Sophie Hermans, whose importance is in carrying the office bag of the prime minister.

Comment: I mean, I see people on street corners spinning business signs for minimum wage TODAY. Why would it be so difficult to believe they have had something similar for much longer.